# Validation check (if 1 equal to some value from database) Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Is there any way in Laravel 5 to check if some value equal with value from database?

Here is what I try to do: I have table `users` and in table users I have additional column `admin_id`. In validation I need to check if `admin_id` form database equal to `1`.

Here is my current code:

```
  $inputs = array(
        'projects' => Input::get('project'),
        'users'    => Input::get('workers')

    );

    $rules = array(
        'projects' => 'required',
        'users'    => 'required'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($inputs,$rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return false;            
       }else{
        return true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know what is `users` input here - is it if from `users` table? If yes, you can then create your rules this way:

```
$rules = array(
        'projects' => 'required',
        'users'    => ['required', 'exists:users,id,admin_id,1']
    );
```

So now it will be verified if `users` matches `user_id` from `users` table where `admin_id` equals `1`.

You should also consider `Laravel 5` Requests objects to validate input. It's much more clean than putting code in Controller/Model/Repository. [More about Requst Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation).

Comment: Great thanks! :) Just edit this: 'users'    => 'required|exists:users,id,admin_id,1'

Comment: Any tutorial for this: "You should also consider Laravel 5 Requests objects to validate input."

Comment: @user2158982 http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation should be enough. You could also look at https://laracasts.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
    $rules = array(
        'projects' => 'required',
        'users' => [
            'required',
            Rule::exists('users', 'id')->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('admin_id', 1);
            }),
        ],
    );
```

Or if the admin_id is dynamic, then use:

```
    $variable = 1;
    $rules = array(
        'projects' => 'required',
        'users' => [
            'required',
            Rule::exists('users', 'id')->where(function ($query) use ($variable) {
                $query->where('admin_id', $variable);
            }),
        ],
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

`$rules = array(
    'users' => 'exists:users,admin_id'
);` where users table name. Can see you also wanna use users as form field name